# filter None value from python list returns: TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I used to filter out None values from a python (3.9.5) list using the "filter" method.
Currently while upgrading several dependencies (pandas 1.3.1, numpy 1.23.5, etc.) I get the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
x = pd.array(['This is', 'some text', None, 'data.'], dtype="string")
x = list(x.unique())
list(filter(None, x))
```

returns: `TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous`

I'll appreciate any good explanation of what was changed and how to solve it, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can also be reproduced by doing just this

```py
>>> bool(x[2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyx", line 446, in pandas._libs.missing.NAType.__bool__
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

As it seems by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/missing.pyx#L395) this is intentional as NA isn't really True or False, its boolean value is ambiguous as it is a "missing value indicator".

```py
    def __bool__(self):
        raise TypeError("boolean value of NA is ambiguous")
```

So basically you can't compare it by calling functions that access the method bool method of a class.

Easiest way to solve this is by @NIKUNJ PATEL

```py
>>> x = list(x.dropna().unique())
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is helps you to remove `None` value with `dropna()` from a list and get available list values.

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.array(['This is', 'some text', None, 'data.'], dtype="string")
x = list(x.dropna().unique())

print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
['This is', 'some text', 'data.']
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Filter is expecting a function and an iterable

You are providing a value and an iterable.

Try this:

```
list( filter( lambda value: not(pd.isna(value)), x ))
```

#### Don't rely on using `None` as the function, if your data is Pandas

That is a shortcut if your iterable contains plain Python values, and you are trying to remove falsy ones from that, as pointed out by @buran below.

However, once your iterable is a pandas array, `None`s have been converted into `pd.NA`s, and therefore will not be removed.

[image]

Comment: As docs state _If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed._ i.e. there is no problem with passing `None` (if OP wants to remove all falsy values).

Comment: Its not filter's fault to not recognise `pd.NA` as None, because `pd.NA` is not None. It is ambiguous, it is mentioned in the error itself.

Comment: Notice that [comparing with `pd.NA` always returns `pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#propagation-in-arithmetic-and-comparison-operations), so `value != pd.NA` will just kick the can down the road — you want `pd.isna()`.